# Requested feature option was not found in this build-in in this lib curl due to build time decision

Tags: c, libcurl

I am trying to create a file on a host and then copy its contents to a remote server. The file name is "Temp.wav" and the data is "1234566890jkjfv". I am facing an issue with the code I am using. I receive the error "feature or option was not found in built-in lib curl due to build time decision". Here is the code I am using:

```c
struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;
struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "sendfile",
             CURLFORM_FILE, "temp.wav",
             CURLFORM_END);

/* Fill in the filename field */
curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "filename", // which we declare temp.wav
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, data, // data which we want to copy to the host which we created
             CURLFORM_END);

/* Fill in the submit field too, even if this is rarely needed */
curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit",
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send",
             CURLFORM_END);

curl = curl_easy_init();
headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);

if(curl) {
    /* what URL that receives this POST */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/examplepost.cgi");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
}
```

How can I fix this issue and create the file and copy its contents?

Comment: I would guess you do not have SSL support in your compiled version. Did you build it yourself? How?

Comment: Yes Ninja ,I build myself

Comment: You'll need to rebuild Curl with the requisite feature(s) enabled.  Or get a pre-built version that has the features you need enabled.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan,Can you suggest me which macro should define or enble in the curl_config.h

Comment: I went to look at the [`curl_formadd()`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html) and find that it is deprecated — use [`curl_mime_init()`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/curl_mime_init.html) instead.  Avoid writing new code using deprecated functions!  Both `curl_formadd()` and `curl_mime_init()` return error indicators — you don't check them.  You might get told more quickly which feature is not included in your build if you test for errors.  Particularly when debugging recalcitrant code, checking for errors from everything, including functions you know "can't fail", can save lots of effort.

Comment: Other than that, I don't have anything much to offer on how to work out what your build of `libcurl` is missing.